# JAVA | Error double cannot be converted to Integer

Tags: java

Un programa que pide qué operación quieres hacer (suma, resta, multiplicar, dividir). Pero me da error en el return total final, que dice:
"**double cannot be converted to Integer**".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HolaMundo{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("Inserte primer numero: ");
        double num1 = scanearNumero();
        System.out.println("Inserte segundo numero: ");
        double num2 = scanearNumero();
        System.out.println("¿Quiéres sumar, restar, multiplicar o dividir?");
        String operacion = scanearOpcion();
        double resultado = calcular(num1,num2,operacion);
        System.out.println("resultado = " + resultado);
    }
    //Método encargado de tomar números por teclado
    public static Double scanearNumero(){
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        var valor = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        return valor;
    }
    //Método encargado de tomar la opcion por teclado
    public static String scanearOpcion() {
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String opcion = scanner.nextLine();
        return opcion;
    }

    //Método encargado de los cálculos
    public static Integer calcular(double num1,double num2, String op){
        double total;
        if (op.equals("sumar"))
            total = num1+num2;
        if (op.equals("restar"))
            total = num1-num2;
        if (op.equals("multiplicar"))
            total = num1*num2;
        if (op.equals("dividir"))
            total = num1/num2;
        return total;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Solo cambia el tipo de valor de retorno que tiene el método `calcular`, es decir, en vez de usarlo como `Integer`, cámbialo a: `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tipo de datos de la funcion no es el mismo del resultado "total", uno es Integer y el otro es double:

`//Método encargado de los cálculos
    public static`**Integer**`calcular(double num1,double num2, String op){`
**double**`total;
        if (op.equals("sumar"))
            total = num1+num2;
        if (op.equals("restar"))
            total = num1-num2;
        if (op.equals("multiplicar"))
            total = num1*num2;
        if (op.equals("dividir"))
            total = num1/num2;
        return total;

    }`

Comment: Gracias eggalardo. ¿Calcular sería una función, un métodos,...? No tengo claros los conceptos. Un saludo.

Comment: Perdón, quise decir método. Normalmente, "función" no se acostumbra en programación orientada a objectos. Un "método" es una función que pertenece a una clase.

Comment: Ok. Gracias por la respuesta.